# Update variable within JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, parsing, variables, localization

Here's a simplified example of something I'm trying to do.

I've got an `input` field which I need to get the value from when the user types in his name and click the "Save changes" `button`.

What I then need is for the `username` variable to update accordingly to what the user typed in. The page has localization features which complicate things slightly. I can't seem to populate the updated value within the `translations` object (anywhere `username` is mentioned, the initialized value is retained and not the last assigned one). This is the part I'm struggling with.

Here's my code:

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p")[0];
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];

var locale = "en";
var username = "";

button.onclick = function() {
  username = input.value;
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-language-key]").forEach(translate);
}

function translate(element) {
  const key = element.getAttribute("data-language-key");
  const translation = translations[locale][key];
  element.innerText = translation;
}

var translations = {
  "en": {
    "message": `Good morning, ${username}!`,
  },
  "fr": {
    "message": `Bonjour, ${username} !`,
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

button {
  margin: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <p data-language-key="message">Good morning, {username}!</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your name...">
  <button>Save changes</button>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript beginner here (if you can ELI5 your answer, I'd appreciate greatly!)

Comment: `username` is declared in one place as a variable, and then updated in the "click" handler. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: Template literals don't save a reference to the variable, the variable is substituted when the literal is read. So entering a new username won't change what's in `translations`.

Comment: Also (FYI), the first 3 `querySelectorAll()` statements should just be `querySelector()` and then you can get rid of the `[0]` indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the variable is substituted when the literal is read, therefore we postpone the reading until it's actually needed. This is done using a function.

```js
var p = document.querySelector("p");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var locale = "en";
var username = "";

button.onclick = function() {
  username = input.value;
  translate(document.querySelector("[data-language-key]"));
}

function translate(element) {
  var key = element.getAttribute("data-language-key")
  const translation = translations[locale][key];
  var text = translation(username);
  element.innerText = text;
}

var translations = {
  "en": {
    "message": () => `Good morning, ${username}!`,
  },
  "fr": {
    "message": () => `Bonjour, ${username} !`,
  }
}
```

```html
<p data-language-key="message">Good morning, {username}!</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your name...">
<button>Save changes</button>
```